# Hierarchy Level labels for d3.partition icicle chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, hierarchy

I am fairly new to D3 and I am trying create a modified version of  the [icicle chart here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html). I need to add labels above the chart to specify the hierarchy level name 
( not the name of each partition but what column name represents the level in the hierarchy). 
I have the names in an array and I have tried to add them to the chart before I bind the actual hierarchical data but I cannot seem to get the labels appear above that chart.
I am not sure whether I need to reduce the amount of  vertical space the chart  takes up or I need to move the labels for each hierarchy level

```
var levels=["LEV 1", "LEV 2", "LEV 3", "LEV 4"];

vis.selectAll("g").append('g') 
      .data(levels).enter()
      .append("text") 
      .attr("dy", ".55em")
      .attr('y', 5)
      .attr('x', function(d,i){ 
        return (i+1)* (w / levels.length) ;})
      .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
      .attr("class", "pHeader") 
      .text(function(d) {  return d; });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your problem is just a matter of leaving room for a margin when you set the size of your plotting area.

This tutorial should help:
[D3 Margin Convention](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563)

You might also want to look at using a D3 axis with an ordinal scale for spacing out your level labels.

Comment: could you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178081/d3-v4-trouble-getting-dendograms-properly-aligned