# D3 v4: trouble getting dendograms properly aligned

Tags: d3.js

My working example can be found at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/SumNeuron/d4744240642294c1e529947192fa8b32) and interacted with at the corresponding [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/SumNeuron/d4744240642294c1e529947192fa8b32). I recommend, however, checking out the raw (full sized) [here](https://bl.ocks.org/SumNeuron/raw/d4744240642294c1e529947192fa8b32/), which shows why there is a lasso tool.

The data is included in the file `index.html` and it is trivial. It is a list of cells (`Object`s) for the heat map.

Currently, most of it works as expected for a draft and things are not properly encapsulated yet for ease of dynamic resizing - although this has been improved in this updated version.

The issue is with the dendrograms. Viewing any of the above links will show you what I currently get. I want to make dendrograms like seen for phylogenic trees or clustering analysis. They are the flat square ones. In addition, I want to place these dendrograms next to the labels. For example, something like this would be nice:

[image]

The built-in functions seem to automatically center the root and expand from there. Which is fine, but makes matching the dendrogram alignment to the labels seemingly impossible, unless I reorder the labels. Also, it doesn't allow for there two be no roots, which can occur.

So I was curious as to how one would go about doing this, much like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/sanshu/1106ceacc42dc99c1b842d954ae32780) example, without having to recode the heatmap aspect.

I found the code there not see easy to understand especially with the lack of comments.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

The layout of this chart is based on this sketch

[image]

where the blue and orange bars are just a default spacing separator between elements (to aid in my own visualization to know how to translate things over) and the buttons are currently set to 0 (as there are none yet)

I also welcome feedback regarding any of this example's implementation. This was my first time doing a lasso tool in d3 so I think it works pretty ok.

Lastly, if anyone can figure out why the x axis labels and the bars for the linked bar chart are not aligned I would greatly appreciate it. I think it might be due to the way the ticks are auto-rendered without consideration for spacing?

Comment: That's a very interesting question. If I were you, I'd drop the built-in dendrogram generator and I'd write my own function to create the dendrograms, which will suit the heatmap perfectly.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for your interest in my question. Yeah, I figured I would have to go that route. Easier said than done though as getting the spacings just right can be tedious. Let me know if you want to take a crack at it.

Comment: This is very interesting, but I have to be honest with you: here at S.O. I have a personal rule, I don't answer a question if it takes more than 5-10 minutes. This, for me, is the boundary between free help and paid consulting. Unfortunately, writing a function like that will take way more than that.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado fair enough. I tend to also avoid answering questions that would take significant time unless I foresee myself having use for the answer I would provide :P  Nonetheless, feel free to look over the source code for what works currently if you want. It has ample comments and could at least foster some ideas for your own work.

Comment: @SumNeuron Have you had any luck with your endeavor? I'm having the same problem right now.